# How to build maven project With existing jar in local maven repository

Tags: maven

I have issue with Project Building in Maven. I have updated some code in one of the dependency jars which is available in Maven Repository .I need to build my project with the jar i have modified.How to do that .Kindly Help me.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Install mvn project**

Make sure to install your changed code into your repository.
Run following maven command for your updated library project.

```
mvn install
```

**2. Check dependency**

Check if the version of your library project match with the dependency entry in your main project pom.
E. g. if you install version "1.1" make sure the dependency entry is also "1.1"